# HTML5 Canvas - Animating color, scale, and rotation

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I'm new to canvas, so pardon the beginner question.  I'm trying to animate a square on a canvas that changes colors, rotates, and scales up and down (this is just for practice).  I'm just trying to grasp all of the concepts and create an example that does all of them at once.

What I want it to do is scale up to a certain amount, then once it reaches that amount, it scales back down to the beginning amount (and then repeats).  The same goes for the color (continue animating, then go backwards through the colors).  How can I accomplish this?

Here's an example of my code that I wrote:

http://jsfiddle.net/ggsFJ/1/

You'll notice a couple bugs:

1. Once the color gets to yellow, it stops animating.
2. The scaling obviously doesn't work.
3. The rotation isn't either clearing the canvas fast enough or something, because it's showing a trail of positions.

Where can I find some resources on accomplishing this?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess minitech has addressed  your problem. Just wanted to say, 
1. framerate is not delay.      
2. you should call the later timeouts after ensuring that first one completes.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that terminology up.  That definitely makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one small problem that's causing all the other problems (well, apart from the yellow - I'm not experiencing that particular one):

```
ctx.restore;
```

That line does nothing. You need to call `ctx.restore` using parentheses. Once you do that, the scaling works, and `clearRect()` will clear a non-transformed rectangle:

```
ctx.restore();
```

[And here's the updated demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ggsFJ/2/)

Comment: Ah. Simple typos... Thanks!  But how can I get it to gradually shrink down to the original scale and not just jump back to it?  What type of loop would I do that would allow me to do that?  Also, to see the color bug, just let the animation run for about 30 seconds or so and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Dan: For the smooth color transitions, it would be better to just use `hsl(..., ..., ...)` color syntax; it's a color wheel already, and any browser that supports `<canvas>` supports it. As for the going up, then going down, you'll need a bit of a fancy modulus trick for that. See my update at http://jsfiddle.net/ggsFJ/8/.

Comment: Awesome!  That is exactly what I'm looking for.  That shows me a lot.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see is with your `restore` method call.
You are just saying `ctx.restore` (possibly by mistake). It should be `ctx.restore();`

Comment: Yep, simple typo.  Thanks, though!